# How can I write Dockerfile for Yesod? "RUN yesod init -n myApp -d postgresql" didn't work as expected

Tags: docker, yesod, dockerfile, docker-compose

I tried to make a simple application with Yesod and PostgreSQL using Docker Compose but `RUN yesod init -n myApp -d postgresql` didn't seem to work as expected.
I defined Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml as below:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM shuny/ghc-7.8.4:latest

MAINTAINER shuny

# Create default config
RUN cabal update
# Add stackage remote repo
RUN sed -i 's/^remote-repo: [a-zA-Z0-9_\/:.]*$/remote-repo: stackage:http:\/\/www.stackage.org\/lts/g' /root/.cabal/config
# Update packages
RUN cabal update
# Generate locale otherwise happy (because of tf-random) will fail
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
RUN echo $LANG
# Install build tools for yesod
RUN cabal install alex happy yesod-bin
# Install library for yesod-postgres
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN yesod init -n myApp -d postgresql
WORKDIR /code/myApp
RUN cabal sandbox init && cabal install --only-dependencies --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
RUN cabal configure && cabal build && cabal install
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
# ADD settings.yml /code/myApp/config/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
database:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432"

web:
    build: .
    tty: true
    command: yesod devel
    volumes:
        - .:/code/
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    links:
        - database
```

and `docker-compose build` returned as below:

```
Step 0 : FROM shuny/ghc-7.8.4:latest
...
Step 17 : WORKDIR /code
---> Running in bf99d0aca48c
---> 37c3c94338d7
Removing intermediate container bf99d0aca48c
Successfully built 37c3c94338d7
```

but when I check like this:

```
$docker-compose run web /bin/bash
root@0fe5fb1a3b20:/code# ls
root@0fe5fb1a3b20:/code#
```

it showed nothing while this commands seem to work as expected:

```
docker run -ti 37c3c94338d7
root@31e94428de37:/code# ls
docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile  myApp  settings.yml
root@31e94428de37:/code# ls myApp/
app                   config         Handler    Model.hs     Settings.hs  test
Application.hs        dist           Import     myApp.cabal  static
cabal.sandbox.config  Foundation.hs  Import.hs  Settings     templates
```

How can I fix it?
I really appliciate any feedback, thank you.

Comment: I guess that it has to do with the `volume` defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file. You are mounting a host directory in the the `/code` directory of the container. That would explain that it works correcly when you are using `docker run` without the `-volume` option.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing strange things with volumes and the `ADD` instruction.

First you build your application inside the image:

```
RUN yesod init -n myApp -d postgresql
WORKDIR /code/myApp
RUN cabal sandbox init && cabal install --only-dependencies --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
RUN cabal configure && cabal build && cabal install
```

Then you add the content of the folder that contains the `Dockerfile` in the `/code` folder of the image. I guess this step is useless.

```
ADD . /code
```

Then, if you run a container without `-volume` option, everything works fine

```
docker run -ti 37c3c94338d7
```

But in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you specified a volume option that overides the `/code` folder in the container with the folder that contains the `docker-compose.yml` file on the host machine. Therefore, you don't have the content generated during the build of your image anymore.

There are two possibilities:

- Don't use the volume instruction in the `docker-compose.yml` file
- Put the content of the `/code/myApp/` folder of the image inside the  `./myApp` folder of the host.

It depends on why you want to use the volume option in `docker-compose.yml`.

---

I don't really know what is your goal. But if what you are trying to do is to access to the files built inside the container from the host machine, maybe this should do what you are looking for:

- Remove the build steps from your Dockerfile
- Run a shell inside a "web" container: `docker-compose run web bash`
- Launch the build commands

So you will have built your application while the volume was mounted and will see the files on the host machine.

- Exit the shell
- Launch Docker Compose normally

If you just want to be able to backup the content of the `/code/myApp/` folder, maybe you should omit the path on the host machine from the `volume` section of docker-compose.yml.

```
volumes:
    - /code/
```

And follow [this section of the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for instruction. I chose the last choice.
But still I wonder how I get the content after building it on container.
Could you tell me?

Comment: Sorry for my lame expression. But that is the answer and what I wanted to know exactly. Thank you for your help!!